# How to reformat an array using php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Import] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [amount] => 50
                    [cost] => 8320
                    [comment] => transportation and others cost: 100  
                    [created] => 2015-06-23 19:21:10
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_sell] => 10
                    [no_contact] => 1
                    [confirmed] => 2
                    [canceled] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Import] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [amount] => 15
                    [cost] => 3000
                    [comment] => 
                    [created] => 2015-06-22 18:10:36
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_sell] => 10
                    [no_contact] => 1
                    [confirmed] => 2
                    [canceled] => 0
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Import] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [amount] => 15
                    [cost] => 2000
                    [comment] => 
                    [created] => 2015-06-23 19:20:15
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_sell] => 10
                    [no_contact] => 0
                    [confirmed] => 0
                    [canceled] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

I want to remove duplicate value of same product_id inside [Import][product_id] but want sum [Import][amount]. My expected array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Import] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [amount] => 65
                    [cost] => 8320
                    [comment] => transportation and others cost: 100  
                    [created] => 2015-06-23 19:21:10
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_sell] => 10
                    [no_contact] => 1
                    [confirmed] => 2
                    [canceled] => 0
                )

        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [Import] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [amount] => 15
                    [cost] => 2000
                    [comment] => 
                    [created] => 2015-06-23 19:20:15
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_sell] => 10
                    [no_contact] => 0
                    [confirmed] => 0
                    [canceled] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

It will be really a gift if anyone give a function to solve this issue.

Comment: your first array is formated.second one that you want is not proper i think. please recheck once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filteredArray = [];

foreach ($array as $productData) {
    if (isset($filteredArray[$productData['Import']['product_id']])) {
        $filteredArray[$productData['Import']['product_id']]['Import']['amount'] += $productData['Import']['amount'];
    }
    else {
        $filteredArray[$productData['Import']['product_id']] = $productData;
    }
}

print_r($filteredArray);
```

Ah.. forgot to mention - `$array` is Your base array.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Removes duplicate summing amount from products array
 * 
 * @param array $array
 * @return array
 */
function removeDuplicates($array)
{
    $idsCount = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $idsCount[$value['Import']['product_id']]['count'] += 1;
        $idsCount[$value['Import']['product_id']]['sum'] += $value['Import']['amount'];
        if ($idsCount[$value['Import']['product_id']]['count'] > 1) {
            unset($array[$key]);
            $array[$idsCount[$value['Import']['product_id']]['key']]['Import']['amount'] = $idsCount[$value['Import']['product_id']]['sum'];
        } else {
            $idsCount[$value['Import']['product_id']]['key'] = $key;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

i know it looks crazy but is formatted on your specific array.